# To scale the images with foreground color and fa-icon on hover and a lightbox link as well

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, transition, lightbox2

The problem is to scale the images with foreground color and fa-icon on hover and a lightbox link as well.
 Below is the html used:-

```
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put the HTML code than i can understand your problem.

and i hope the following link is useful for solve problem

[setting opacity for background image with url in css](http://www.tagwith.com/question_550757_setting-opacity-for-background-image-with-url-in-css)